# Using Guzzle to fetch Instagram API: Connection Rejected

Tags: php, laravel, instagram-api, guzzle

I am using the Guzzle package in my local Laravel application to fetch my recent posts on Instagram, it was working for a few days but has stopped working and I can't figure out why. I get a ConnectException error :/

This is the rejection error I get:

> at CurlFactory::createRejection(object(EasyHandle), array('errno' =>
>   7, 'error' => '', 'url' =>
>   'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=MYTOKENGOESHERE',
>   'content_type' => null, 'http_code' => 0, 'header_size' => 0,
>   'request_size' => 0, 'filetime' => -1, 'ssl_verify_result' => 0,
>   'redirect_count' => 0, 'total_time' => 0.013781, 'namelookup_time' =>
>   0.031012, 'connect_time' => 0.0, 'pretransfer_time' => 0.0, 'size_upload' => 0.0, 'size_download' => 0.0, 'speed_download' => 0.0,
>   'speed_upload' => 0.0, 'download_content_length' => -1.0,
>   'upload_content_length' => -1.0, 'starttransfer_time' => 0.0,
>   'redirect_time' => 0.0, 'redirect_url' => '', 'primary_ip' => '',
>   'certinfo' => array(), 'primary_port' => 0, 'local_ip' => '',
>   'local_port' => 0)) in CurlFactory.php (line 150)

I can confirm its got nothing to do with the endpoint as I can make the request to the same URL and Access Token in Postman from the same local machine successfully.

Here is the code I am using:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=MYACCESSTOKEN";
$res = $client->request('GET', $url);
return $res->getStatusCode();
```

Comment: are you only fetching posts right ? without login ?

Comment: That's correct, but as far as I am aware you still need to use an access code for this. (which you retrieve by granting access)